# How to sum in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a below table and i just want to sum column `_10` & `_12` column but i am getting error

```
 _2|_10|_12|
+------+---+---+
|yearID|  H| 3B|
|  2004|  0|  0|
|  2006|  0|  0|
|  2007|  0|  0|
|  2008|  0|  0|
|  2009|  0|  0|
|  2010|  0|  0|
|  1954|131|  6|
|  1955|189|  9|
|  1956|200| 14|
|  1957|198|  6|
|  1958|196|  4|
|  1959|223|  7|
|  1960|172| 11|
|  1961|197| 10|
|  1962|191|  6|
|  1963|201|  4|
|  1964|187|  2|
|  1965|181|  1|
|  1966|168|  1|
|  1967|184|  3|
|  1968|174|  4|
|  1969|164|  3|
|  1970|154|  1|
|  1971|162|  3|
|  1972|119|  0|
|  1973|118|  1|
|  1974| 91|  0|
|  1975|109|  2|
|  1976| 62|  0|
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It also would be very helpful if you could post your code.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean about sum. If you mean sum whole column's values, you can use agg function. Or if you want to sum like _10 + _12 and create a new column then use withColumn function

```
>>> data = sc.parallelize([
...     ('yearID','H','3B'),
...     ('2004','0','0'),
...     ('2006','0','0'),
...     ('2007','0','0'),
...     ('2008','0','0'),
...     ('2009','0','0'),
...     ('2010','0','0'),
...     ('1954','131','6'),
...     ('1955','189','9'),
...     ('1956','200','14'),
...     ('1957','198','6')
...     ])
>>> 
>>> cols = ['_2','_10','_12']
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data,cols)
18/10/01 04:22:48 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+------+---+---+
|    _2|_10|_12|
+------+---+---+
|yearID|  H| 3B|
|  2004|  0|  0|
|  2006|  0|  0|
|  2007|  0|  0|
|  2008|  0|  0|
|  2009|  0|  0|
|  2010|  0|  0|
|  1954|131|  6|
|  1955|189|  9|
|  1956|200| 14|
|  1957|198|  6|
+------+---+---+

>>> df.agg({'_10':'sum','_12':'sum'}).show()
+--------+--------+
|sum(_12)|sum(_10)|
+--------+--------+
|    35.0|   718.0|
+--------+--------+

>>> df.withColumn('new_col', df['_10']+df['_12']).show()
+------+---+---+-------+
|    _2|_10|_12|new_col|
+------+---+---+-------+
|yearID|  H| 3B|   null|
|  2004|  0|  0|    0.0|
|  2006|  0|  0|    0.0|
|  2007|  0|  0|    0.0|
|  2008|  0|  0|    0.0|
|  2009|  0|  0|    0.0|
|  2010|  0|  0|    0.0|
|  1954|131|  6|  137.0|
|  1955|189|  9|  198.0|
|  1956|200| 14|  214.0|
|  1957|198|  6|  204.0|
+------+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: Can you please help me out how i save the output

Comment: where do you want to save? save to file or db? if file, what format do you want to use?csv, parquet.. etc?

Comment: I want to save output in normal text file. so how we save as text file